# What is the reason for which a function's return type cannot be var?

Tags: c#-3.0

e.g.

```
public var SomeMethod()
{ 
   return "hello";
}
```

error:
The contextual keyword `var` may only appear within a local variable declaration

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# only supports type inference for local variables. It doesn't support it for the return type of a non-anonymous function. This is a design decision. It's possible that they change it in the future. Languages like F# do in fact support return type inference so there's no inherent impossibility involved here. Of course, sometimes, the inferred return type may be ambiguous and requires further clarification in the languages that support it:

```
// not real C#:
public var Method(bool returnInt) {
    if (returnInt) return 42; else return true;
}
// what's the return type of Method is going to be? ValueType? object? ...?
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you read [Why no var on fields?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields.aspx):

> In my recent request for things that make you go hmmm, a reader notes that you cannot use "var" on fields.

Now you don't want to use `var` for a field but you do want to use it for another purpose other than how it is specified.  That article should give you a little insight into the compiler implementation around the `var` feature (and why, perhaps, `var` is not a valid return type).

Now, all that being said, it would be perfectly valid for the return type of a method to be inferred by the type of the return expression.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a potentially ambiguous situation, a slight enhancement of your question:

```
public var SomeMethod()  { 
    return DateTime.Now.Second % 2 == 0 ? "hello" : 3;
}
```

Should the compiler raise an *error* or infer type `System.Object`?
Only at runtime can the correct type be resolved between `int` and `string`.

---

`var` must be used on the left side of an initialization statement because its **type is inferred by the C# compiler** from the resulting data type on the right side.

```
var thing = 3;
// infers System.Int32 from right side.

var thing = 3L;
// infers System.Int64 from right side.

// This also applies to methods and things that have a defined type on the right side:
var thing = obj.AnyMethod();
```

If you could use var in place of the method return type, how could the C# compiler easily infer that type from all the logic inside the method?

```
var MyCall() { // ??? could be various things really
    // lots of logic...
}
```

### Available C# alternative

However, what you might be looking for in the C# language is to allow an interchangeable return type from your method via a [Type Parameter and Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) like so:

```
T MyCall<T>() { 
    // lots of logic...
```

The caller can then specify the type that will be returned. Example:

An int.

```
var result = MyCall<int>();
// var will infer System.Int32
```

A string.

```
var result = MyCall<string>();
// var will infer System.String
```

Comment: I see your point, but this is not a strong argument. Global type inference is certainly possible and it's implemented in some languages (even with parametric polymorphism). The answer to your question would be: you'll define very specific rules for the statements to infer the return type of a method, at least in some cases. (similar to the way "reachable" statements are defined in the C# spec).

Comment: I'm intending to imbue reason, hopefully some insight, a practical workaround, within the context of C# 3.0, although you're right in some languages it's possible.